# Implementing a counter as a Scheme procedure

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, counter, procedure

I am reading "The Scheme programming language" and I have a question about one of the examples that creates a counter.

```
(define count  
  (let ([next 0])  
    (lambda ()  
      (let ([v next])  
        (set! next (+ next 1))  
        v))))
```

What I do not understand is why doesn't the value of 'next' reset to 0 every time the 'count' procedure is called? I come from a Java/C# background and I imagine that the let is executed each time count is called resulting in next being assigned 0.
I know it is a very beginner-ish question but I will be very thankful if you could provide some explanation.

P.S When I was learning Haskell I found the books I read to provide much more explanation on WHY things happened and I didn't have such noob question whereas it seem that "The Scheme programming language" isn't the typical beginner's book.

Comment: This question is essentially the same as the one I linked, even though the arithmetic operations are a bit different. Short answer: this works because we're creating a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) that "remembers" the value between calls

Comment: Thank you for the answer and links provided!

Comment: "The Scheme programming language" is indeed not really a beginner's book. There are two good ones available for free online: [How to design Programs, "HtDP"](http://htdp.org/) and [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, "SICP"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). SICP can also be found in PDF and ePub formats.